# Unable to get the dates right in xtick labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I am trying to make candlestick using rectangle patch in matplotlib, but the dates on xaxis are not coming right. I had to use a number as x value to create the rectangle shape, and now I want to replace these values with corresponding dates in the dataframe index.
Heres the code:`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

df = yf.download('adaniports.ns', '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01')
df.rename(columns={'Adj Close': 'Adj_close'}, inplace= True)

def candlestick(df, colorup= '#2bff1c', colordown= '#ff5e00'):
df.reset_index(inplace= True)
df['Days_num'] = df.Date.apply(lambda x: x - df.Date[0])
df.set_index('Date', inplace= True)
df.Days_num = df.Days_num.apply(lambda x: x/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize= (12, 8))
ax.plot([df.Days_num, df.Days_num], [df.High, df.Low], color= 'k', solid_capstyle='round', linewidth= 0.8)
for x in range(len(df.index)):
    if df.Close[x] > df.Open[x]:
        color = colorup
    else:
        color = colordown
    rec = mpl.patches.Rectangle((df.Days_num[x] - 0.25, df.Open[x]), 0.5, (df.Close[x] - df.Open[x]), facecolor= color,\
                               edgecolor= 'k', linewidth= 0.5, capstyle= 'round', zorder= 3)
    ax.add_patch(rec)
    ax.set_xticklabels([x.strftime('%d-%m-%y') for x in df.index.tolist()])
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())
ax.grid(True)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()

candlestick(df)
```

Here is the output:
[image]
As you can see, the range is one year, but the x-ticks only plot for 1 month.

I know that there are libraries like mplfinance for this, but I would rather do it this way as I need to make customisations on it,  which is difficult in those libraries.

Comment: The current X axis has 8 ticks in 50 units based on the date number. I'm using a list of data frame indexes, so there are 8 ticks from the very beginning. `x.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())` and `fig.autofmt_xdate()` are unnecessary. What is the desired date/time interval?

Comment: I simply want to use the dates for the x axis, presently it is df.Date_num column, which is what I used to calculate the x position of the rectangle patch. I want the corresponding df.index(which is datetimeindex) to be seen as the xticklabels.

Comment: If you want to use 7-day units for market business days, you can use the following method. `ax.set_xticks(df.Days_num.tolist()[::7]);ax.set_xticklabels([x.strftime('%d-%m-%y') for x in df.index.tolist()[::7]], rotation=90)`

Comment: My comment is an example of creating an x-axis with an interval of 7 acquired dates each. It is not a 7 day interval because there are also holidays.

Comment: Ok yes you are right, thank you for the solution to this.

Comment: You didn't ask your question in a way for others help you accomplish your final goal.   You say your ultimate goal was some particular customizations, but you assume the solution is to write your own candlestick function.  Maybe so, maybe not.  If you state the ultimate customization goal, perhaps someone knows a package that can already do that, or perhaps someone can guide you in an *easy way* to customize another package.

Comment: Just to elaborate on my previous comment:  Here you are looking to solve only *one* problem (date axis) on the path to writing your own candlestick function.  Maybe that is the only such problem you will encounter, maybe not.  I can tell you from experience as the maintainer of mplfinance, there are potentially many such problems to solve in developing and maintaining candlestick plotting functionality.  Therefore, unless writing your own candlestick function is your ultimate goal, I recommend you state the ultimate goal and see what solutions people may have.

Comment: @Daniel Goldfarb, I wish to mark certain eventful days using scatter plot on the candle chart and maybe use some hlines to mark price range. I tried to do all these with mplfinance package. But it looks like such operations are not possible at the moment. I even fiddled with the old candlestick_ohlc package. so I think it would be less complicated to have a candlestick done on pyplot for easy customisation. If you think otherwise, I can post an elaborate question about the customisation with mplfinance.

Comment: @Rockoos [**This tutorial**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb) shows how you can mark specific dates or candles with a scatter plot (for example, see cell **`In [10]`** and below in that tutorial) and [**this other tutorial**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/using_lines.ipynb) shows how to set horizontal lines at specific price levels (for example see cell **`In [5]`** in [the tutorial](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/using_lines.ipynb)).  Let me know this approach doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Daniel Goldfarb Thank you. Very interesting, I will go through them.